# How can I prevent the ID from showing in the datalist element?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to utilize the datalist element.  Everything is working with 1 little hitch.  The selectable list is showing 2 columns, both the street_id and street columns.  I need the street_id that will be submitted but dont want the street_id to show in the datalist.

```html
<?php

require 'connect_mysqli.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM streets";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
?>
<form action="test.php" name="test" method = "post">
<datalist id="street" name="streets">
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['street_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['street']; ?></option>
    <?php 
    } 
?>
</datalist>
<input type="text" name="street_val" id="test" autocomplete="off" list="street">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php 
mysqli_close($con); 
//test the output value
echo $_POST['street_val'];//
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have coded a select list - which has separate values for display and returned values.  In the datalist, you only need value="" for options and then it will only return that value.  Also better to keep the server code and display code separate: i.e. populate or build the array in the PHP with your query, then in the HTML only display it.

Comment: If I understand correctly your suggestion will only show the street and not the  street_id which is what I want displayed, but I need the street_id to be used later in a query. I am not seeing how to capture the id.

Comment: Use a select element : with value returning the ID and the innHTML showing the description

Comment: Nicholas, I am needing to be able to add a value that does not currently exist.  I am new to all of this and can't understand how to use the SELECT element and allow additions to be made with java or jquery.  I have seen some examples but it seems to be over my head.

Comment: a datalist has <option value="display"> (one parameter is displayed and returned) where a select list has <option value="id">display</option> (one value is returned, another is displayed).  That was the question, being able to dynamically add options, that is another question (and yes, it is more complex).  jQuery is useful for that sort of thing.